# How do I list all the objects in a folder of a Google Cloud Bucket in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

In python the way I get my bucket is:

```
gs_conn = connect_gs(gs_access_key_id='accessid', gs_secret_access_key='secretaccesskey')
gs_conn.get_bucket(bucketname)
```

I can list all of the objects in that bucket by:

```
for obj in gs_conn.get_bucket(bucketname):
    print obj.name
```

However, I would like to list all of the objects inside of a folder inside of a bucket. For example I want to list of all the objects inside of /Animals/Dogs/. How do I do this in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [get_all_keys](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/gs.html#boto.gs.bucket.Bucket.get_all_keys) method of the bucket. For example:

```
bucket = gs_conn.get_bucket(bucketname)
for obj in bucket.get_all_keys(prefix='Animals/Dogs/'):
    print obj.name
```